# how to reset auto-increment int when deleting all data from database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my database

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                 KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_PRICE + " LONG, " +
                KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL);" 
                );
```

and this is the method for deleting all data

```
public void deleteall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);

    }
```

and this is the method for deleting a particular data

```
public void deletentry(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = " + l,null);

    }
```

Here using the data I deleted but incremented row-id remains there, which I want to reset to 1 as the data is deleted also if I delete a particular data the row-id changes it's value in a sequence manner there should be no gap in between row-id.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're basically wanting the table to always start at one and have no gaps? For example, if you delete item 3, you want everything from 4 on up to be resequenced starting at 3?

Comment: yes i want the same ,, wanting the table to always start at one nd have no gaps , just like ur example.

Comment: FYI - the max key is stored in the table sqlite_sequence.  Certainly people do manipulate/delete it but I have no idea how safe that is and how it relates to transaction state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `autoincrement` is your best option. If your goal is to create a simple numbered table with no gaps, it may be much easier to handle this using a table with a column for you to manually keep up with your ID's.

If you created a table like that, you could then write helper methods in your code for the following operations: addColumn, removeColumn, emptyTable.

Your `addColumn` method would query the table and determine the `max(ID)` then add 1 and use that number for the next entry.

Your `removeColumn` method could remove the entry by ID, then use that ID to resequence everything above it. Or, if order is not important, it could take the last row and re-id it to fill in the gap.

Your `emptyTable` method could remove all entries.

**Update**
Maybe this can get you started. The methods would need to be defined in your program. You would have to put the code inside them and then set them up to be called.

For example:

```
public void addColumn(String category, long date, String details) {
    //code here would need to determine the max of ID and add one
    //to it. the sql below would retrieve max, i dont know the sql lite code
    //off the top of my head.
    //SELECT MAX(ID) FROM DATABASE_TABLE;
    int newID = max + 1;
    //add row to the database using newID
}

public void removeColumn(int id) {
    //remove column from database
    //DELETE FROM DATABASE_TABLE WHERE ID = id;
    //change last entry to use id
    //UPDATE DATABASE_TABLE SET ID = id WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM DATABASE_TABLE);
}

public void emptyTable() {
    //DELETE FROM DATABASE_TABLE;
}
```

To call these methods, you would call them like any other java method in your class:

```
addColumn(12, 'text', (long)100, 'text');
removeColumn(10);
emptyTable();
```

Comment: can you write a small code how to use this addcolumn removeColumn, emptyTable it would be very helpul to me.nd thanks..

Answer (score 2):

SQLite keeps the largest ROWID in the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. You can delete that table as:

```
db.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE","NAME = ?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQLite `AUTOINCREMENT` is not guaranteed to work as you want. Quoting the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has
>   a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.
>   The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is
>   one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert. If
>   the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used. If the
>   largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer
>   (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive
>   candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously
>   used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of
>   attempts, the insert operation fails with an SQLITE_FULL error. If no
>   negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically
>   generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero.

If you need this specific behaviour you described, the only solution would be for you to manually control the `KEY_ROWID` for your table, making sure you properly account for inserts and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete your table from `SQLite_Sequence` using

```
sqlDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'");
```